# Alternative way to access folder options

Tags: regedit

found this guide over at pctools.com, and I'm curious if there is still other way for others to access folder options if I have already disabled it. And if you know if there is other way to access hidden files if the folder options is disabled please do tell. 
http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not deny those users access to the `.cpl` file using file permissions?  It doesn't get more secure than that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a computer joined to a domain, there is a group policy called "Hide specified Control Panel items" under:

```
User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel
```

This will prohibit access to any applet you specify, no matter how the user tries to access it.

There is also a policy specifically for Folder Options called "Removes the Folder Options menu item from the Tools menu" which does the same function, found under:

```
User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer
```

I suspect that under the covers these policies just set the registry value that you've found.

Comment: does this trick succeeds in securing that certain file, if the file is to be launched using the command line?

Comment: Yes, the first policy I mentioned is the official way to disable all access to Control Panel applets, no matter how they try to access it.